# Trouble implementing a responsive navigation menu using CSS Grid – how can I ensure proper alignment across different screen sizes?"

Tags: responsive-design, media-queries, css-grid, web-development-server

In the css how can we change the alignment across different screen sizes?
Attempted: Implemented a navigation menu using CSS Grid, adjusted grid properties, and utilized media queries for responsiveness.
Expectation: Expected consistent alignment and functionality across different devices and screen sizes, seeking advice or examples to achieve this using CSS Grid.